# Fortran runtime error 'Bad integer for item 3 in list input'

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am trying to open an existing file using the open command. The program compiles successfully but on execution I get this error saying bad integer for item 0 in list input. This is the code I've used.

```
CHARACTER*10,DIMENSION(5) :: FN,LN
INTEGER, DIMENSION(5) :: RNO,CLASS
REAL, DIMENSION(5) :: PHY,CHEM,MATH,COMP,ENG
REAL, DIMENSION(5) :: TOT,P 
OPEN (10, FILE = 'SDA', STATUS = 'OLD')

DO I=1,5,1
READ(10,*),FN(I),LN(I),RNO(I),CLASS(I)
READ(10,*)PHY(I),CHEM(I),MATH(I),COMP(I),ENG(I)
END DO 

OPEN(21, FILE = 'FILEN', STATUS='NEW')

WRITE(21,*),'FNAME    LNAME     RNO   CLASS' 

DO I=1,5,1
WRITE(21,*),FN(I),LN(I),RNO(I),CLASS(I)
END DO
```

file content

```
FNAME     LNAME      RNO   CLASS
 ALOK      TATA       4531 12
 SAMAY     SONI       4532 12
 ARJUN     MANI       4533 12
 TATWA     DAS        4534 12
 BRUCE     WAYNE      4535 12

 PHY CHE MAT COM ENG
 90. 90. 90. 80. 99.
 80. 80. 80. 70. 80.
 70. 60. 60. 70. 60.
 60. 70. 80. 90. 90.
 80. 80. 80. 80. 80.
```

Comment: Are there declarations to type the variables?  I hope so. (Did you use `implicit none`?)  Please show the declarations.  Is `FN` a string rather than an integer?   Are the contents of the file consistent with the read statement?  The error indicates that the file contents are not consistent with an integer.  Please show the file.

Comment: Yes i have used implicit none. FN is a string. Below is the content of the existing file.

Comment: The file has 6 strings, then 2 numbers -- if spaces are meant to be the deliminator.  You read 2 strings, then 2 numbers.  It is necessary to put strings in the file between " " for list-directed IO?  I haven't used list-directed IO for strings in a long time.

Comment: Is it not simply that you need to discard the single header line before attempting to read the data?  [With a `read(10,*)` before the loop.]

Comment: I have tried that but i keep getting a expected character got integer error. I tried to read the first two values alone using format specifiers, it executes but in the output file im getting only the first character followed by lots of junk value

Comment: As I read it the program first reads 1 'header' line, then 1 'data' line, and then loops around.  That isn't what the input file shown contains.  Perhaps OP needs two loops, one to read the header lines, then one to read the data lines.

Comment: It's been a while since I've written Fortran, but the comma between READ(10,*) and FN(I) doesn't look write to me.